# How can i make the datalist bigger?

Tags: html

I would like to know how can i resize the datalist and the text of options so it fits my needs.As you can see in the picture the dropdown menu is extremely small [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80HPZ.png). I am sorry if the question is stupid or something but i am not really good at it.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Add your code and a fiddle

Comment: I dont think its necessary i think my question is simple enough.I jusst game an example..

Answer (score 0):

what you need to do is this

using css, call the option tag to edit the datalist .e.g

```
select option{
    height:50px;
    font-size:35px;
}
```

and it produces what you want.
[image]